# Can't get css fade in triggered by javascript to fade in

Tags: javascript, css

I want to fade in an error message if there is one by adding a class to a div. The error message does show up currently but it doesn't fade in.

Here is the html. This is just an empty div and the error class doesn't actually contain any styling.

```
<div class="error"></div>
```

This is the javascript which triggers the displaying of the error message:

```
  const showError = document.querySelector('.error');
  showError.classList.add("error-message-fade-in");
  showError.innerHTML = errorMessages;
```

And here is the css:

```
  .error-message-fade-in {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1000ms;
    color: #de5959;
    background-color: #ffe9e9;
    padding: 20px 26px;
  }
```

Comment: does the `.error` class have an `opacity` of less than 1? I ask because if not, the default is 1, so the transition will be from 1 to 1, so there will be no visible transition.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, I didn't have the .error set to an opacity of 0. I just tried that but what happens now is that a gap in the view occurs where the div would fade in but it is invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working fine, just make sure you have set the properties needed for the transition to actually take effect. Set the initial `opacity` of the div as 0, this will make the element invisible, and add the transition time as well; after that you just have to add the class with the `opacity: 1`, and the transition will happen.

```js
function fadeError() {
  const showError = document.querySelector('.error');
  showError.classList.add("error-message-fade-in");
  showError.innerHTML = 'Error';

}
```

```css
.error {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.error-message-fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1000ms;
  color: #de5959;
  background-color: #ffe9e9;
  padding: 20px 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="error"></div>

<button type="button" onclick="fadeError()">Fade</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For some reason when I look in console it shows that `.error-message-fade-in {` has opacity: 1 crossed out as well as transition. But `.error {` is showing opacity: 0. And the div is basically invisible

Comment: Are you trying this on your code? Make sure the .error rule is defined before the .error-message-fade-in, I think it might be overriding it

Comment: Ah, okay. That was it

Answer (score 0):

here link of [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harshad_prajapati/72xkbqcz/) of solution

- set the initialize opacity `0` to `.error`